# Can I use more than one USB Gadgets with the raspberrypi zero?

Tags: usb, serial, ethernet, pi-zero, storage

it's my first question over here. I'm wondering if I could use more than one USB Gadget [like in that Tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/) just that I use g_ether and the mass storage. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look into `g_multi` gadget, which supports multiple functions in one configuration:

- a CDC Ethernet (ECM) link
- a CDC ACM (serial port) link
- a USB Mass Storage device

If you want to connect your Pi to Windows, read [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_multi.txt) describing how to get the right drivers installed for each function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can by buying a USB Hub and plugging it into the Raspberry Pi Zero (I would recommend **2.0 and over**).[image: An Example Of One USB Hub]

Comment: You should probably also recommend that the op buys a powered hub because of the low max power output of the Pi zero

Comment: watch out about compatibility of raspberry pi zero and usb hubs that seems not simply to be related to the hub being a powered one but specifically on chipset compatibility like many users are reporting. have a look at this list that has been created so far: http://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs even though only one at the top seems to be specific for the zero.

Comment: the official hub has a micro USB connector for the pi zero and has the option to use external power.

Comment: This answer completely fails to address the question, which is about the **USB Composite Gadget drivers**, not about plugging more devices in downstream ports.